# I found this tiny transparent creature in my aquarium - what is it?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image]

Please help me identify this 1-2 mm nearly transparent animal which I found in my salt water aquarium.

Comment: Can you give some kind of indication of size, is it a freshwater or salt aquarium?

Comment: Can you say also if it's moving or not, is there any sign of a rudimentary (presumably transparent) shell? (I'm thinking freshwater limpet, but the symmetry may not be right).

Comment: Hi.. It may be in 1 Or 2 mm and i just 2days back only bought the aquarium and filled with salted tap water.. It's moving and it's walking with it's legs by walls only.

Comment: It's very transparent like water..

Comment: Oh, those things are legs, that's a whole different thing. Now I'm thinking some kind of arthropod, perhaps a parasite, will look into it.

Comment: I thought it might be a turtle or crab

Comment: I moved it small glass jar today morning only. Can I put it ian that har for some days.. Do you have any idea approximately how many days it will takes to find out what it would be...

Comment: with a good picture i could tell you what it is right now,please take a better picture by turning off the light in the room so only the water in the tank is lit and be sure to focus the camera properly.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; and 3) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information as comments are ephemeral and so should only be used to communicate about the post. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: Initial thought was a Triops species. But your specimen is too small for that. Likely some kind of crustacean.

Comment: i had that with my tropical fish, i found 2-3 it wasn't too much of a contagion though it was not good.

Answer (score 1):

Now THAT is a fish louse in the [Argulidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argulidae) family. They are bloodsucking parasites that attach themselves to fish with those round suckers near their head and feed with needle-like mouthparts. Needless to say, I'd advise you to find and eliminate as many as you can, as they'll be harming your fish with their bites.

Comment: Time to him read on all the fish parasites that affect common goldfish and tropical fish and see what to be wary of.